# Strange behaviour when screencasting

Tags: 12.04, screen-corruption

Since an update I did yesterday I am not able to screencast any video using Kazam, Recordmydesktop or even ffmpeg/aviconv. After the upgrade to some libraries (A normal update that showed in Update manager) the problem was this:

- When doing the screencast, scrolling inside an Apps window like Firefox, Chrome or Gedit is not shown. The video only shows the last image it recognized before I started scrolling. For example with Gedit, I have a lot of text on it and when I start to scroll down, the video only shows what I had in the beginning while I listen to myself talk about what is in the rest of the file (Which is not shown in the video).
- When opening a window, for example again Gedit or Chrome it might not show in the video, it will just show the desktop without the window opened.

I do not see any error with dmesg, syslog or others. What can I check to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in a later update. The update is already included in 12.10. For 12.04 I only needed to update to the latest packages.